# Installing Anaconda on a Secondary Drive (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I'm running Windows 10 Home, and I recently downloaded Anaconda because I wanted to be able to use Spyder, and wasn't really anticipating how much storage space it would take up, so I had to uninstall it.

However, my computer has two hard drives--a 100gb C:/ drive that windows boots off of and a much larger D:/ drive meant for storage. A lot of anaconda's largest files seem to be saved to C:/Users/[User], which is still on my C drive. And taking up space that I don't really have to spare.

Is there a way to tell Anaconda during installation (or initial run, possibly, it looks like) that it should save those files somewhere else? One of the environment variables, maybe?

If not I guess I'm open to suggestions for other Python IDEs that are smaller or can be put entirely on a secondary drive.

Comment: I'm with this problem right now. did you already solve it?

Comment: @AndersonOliveira Unfortunately, I ended up simply installing spyder as a standalone to save space and regretted it when I went to update versions of Python and things went weird. I'd see if a [WinPy distribution](https://winpython.github.io/) can do whatever you're hoping to achieve with Anaconda. It also has some support for virtual environments and package management and was built to be portable. It's what I'm using now. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to work with spyder and not the rest of the software that comes bundled with Anaconda, you can just

```
pip install PyQt5 
pip install spyder
```

[Here is a guide for installing Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html).

Comment: I had thought about this originally, but I thought I'd seen something on their website about new updates only coming through the anaconda distribution. Not seeing that anywhere now, though, so maybe I misread. If so, that's probably the way to go.